# Easiest way to grab and stream depth data from Asus Xtion with OpenNI to web browser

Tags: browser, openni, asus-xtion

I am using Debian and my computer acts as a server, with a static IP address.

I connected an ASUS Xtion Pro Live to it. It works and I can get both depth and RGB values by using the sample application provided by OpenNI.

My question is: what is the *easiest* and yet *efficient* way to stream the data to a web browser of another computer connected to the same network (e.g. grayscale image or point cloud)?

Any suggestion or example are very appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: I think that you can send them as images, point clouds consumes more memory... Though if you need the depth values you need to write them in something like yml or xml and try compressing the data before sending.... This is just a suggestion, hopefully someone will post a nice answer

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For now I am thinking about websockets and node.js... Hope someone who has some experience will share some suggestions!